# ATI Radeon 9200 Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, radeon

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS in my old computer and it worked alright until I installed Ubuntu 12.10.

I tried updating to 13.04 to see if this fixed it, but unfortunately it didn't, Does  anyone knows how to make this driver work? Everything seems to be like ten times slower or so on the screen (everything but the mouse ),

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same card for a while.. There are no Linux drivers.. I solved the issue by installing the "gnome-session-fallback" package which replaces Unity with GNOME, much less system resources needed.